# Music service destroyed unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-service, playback

I've noticed lately that my `PlaybackService`, a subclass of `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`, is getting destroyed unexpectedly. Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch the app and play music.
2. Send the app to the background.
3. After a couple minutes, the service's `onDestroy()` method is called.

The service does not get destroyed if I keep my app in the foreground. I know it sounds like my `PlaybackService` is a bound service, but it is not. I explicitly call `startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlaybackService.class))` whenever playback is about to start (step 1). I subsequently call `playbackService.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)` from my playback notification manager to show a relevant notification with playback controls and the song's metadata. Considering this, I only expect the service to be destroyed if I explicitly stop the service or, in a rare case, when the system is in dire need for memory.

The only places where I explicitly stop the service is from within the `onTaskRemoved()` callback and in a delayed stop handler that is run after playback has been paused for two minutes, neither of which get called since the app (task) never gets removed - it still exists in the 'recent apps' list - and playback is ongoing up until `onDestroy()` is called; neither I nor the system pause playback in my tests.

It seems like this issue started to occur after I updated my phone to `8.1.0` yesterday, but I can't 100% confirm this. I'm not able to reproduce this issue when testing the same conditions on an emulator running API 23.

Any thoughts on why my playback service is getting destroyed on my `8.1.0` device?

Comment: So what is your target version?

Comment: @Xenolion I'm targeting API 27.

Comment: Then try to use this `Context.startForegroundService()` instead of `Context.startService()` Try and give me a feedback!

Comment: And once your service is started call this method in it  `startForeground()`

Comment: @Xenolion good suggestion. However, I'm still seeing the same issue when calling `startForegroundService()` (followed by an immediate call to `startForeground()`) instead of `startService()`.

Comment: @Xenolion I take that back. Your solution did work, but I had a line in my notification manager that called `stopForeground(false)` whenever playback was paused so the user could swipe away the playback notification. I'll need to find a workaround for this. Anyways, your suggestion solved the root issue. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Current predicament: I want to allow users to swipe away the playback notification when music is paused and keep the service alive and in the foreground until that happens. Currently, I set `stopForeground(false)` when music is paused to allow the user to swipe away the notification. However, the notification will now be automatically removed by the system if the app is in the background, so the user can't resume playback from the system notification drawer.

Comment: I think those may be android modifications starting from Oreo. If you have not yet found a good solution you can check in the documentation a method to avoid that or else show another notification when a user pause the music! I will try helping you with that once I get to my pc. Currently using mobile phone!

Comment: @Xenolion Unfortunately haven't found a way to work around my predicament via an API method. I hate to have to resort to it, but I may need to show a copy, non-foreground notification when playback is paused. :/

Comment: Show another notification when a user pauses the music!

Answer (score 2):

As @Xenolion mentioned in the comments, this issue was caused by calling `Context.startForeground()` instead of `Context.startForegroundService()` on Oreo+ devices. Solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(application, MusicService.class);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```